# After switching to TeX Live from MiKTeX, Kile's live preview feature doesn't work anymore

Tags: errors, miktex, texlive, kile

A few days ago I switched from MiKTeX to TeX Live in order to make both my Mac and Windows computer be on the same platform. I've been ripping my hair out trying to figure out why Kile suddenly decided to stop working. To be clear, the regular compile function works perfectly. But the single most alluring feature of Kile, the live preview feature, does not work.

On the "Log and Messages" screen, this is what shows up:

```
[LivePreview-PDFLaTeX] test.tex => test.pdf (pdflatex)
[LivePreview-PDFLaTeX] finished with exit code 1
Cannot open log file; did you run LaTeX?
```

This is what shows up on the "Output" screen:

```
*****
*****     LivePreview-PDFLaTeX output: 
*****     cd "F:/"
*****     pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -output-directory=C:/Users/Kevin/AppData/Roaming/.kde/share/apps/kile/livepreview/preview-p0caaa/ test.tex
*****
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/W32TeX)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
! I can't find file `test.tex'.
<*> test.tex

(Press Enter to retry, or Control-Z to exit)
Please type another input file name
! Emergency stop.
<*> test.tex

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on "C:/Users/Kevin/AppData/Roaming/.kde/share/apps/kile
/livepreview/preview-p0caaa//texput.log".
```

So, do any of you have any idea why Kile is having problems?

Comment: "`p0caaa/ test.tex`" - you have a space there.

Comment: @MartinSchröder I did remove the space, it still doesn't work.

Comment: I'm having the same problem described above (same log message, exit code, and question about whether I ran LaTeX). In this case, I'm using Kile to run PDFLaTeX. On this very same file it worked without any errors 5 months ago. Now, it won't finish. I'm running it on an arch linux machine working in dwm. Any ideas? It must have something to do with an update.

Comment: @RichardBarrett I did finally manage to fix it by crawling by to MiKTeX.